# Why my regular expression doesn't match this?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Please help me with this problem. This is my htaccess rule :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(GET)
RewriteRule ^ws/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([A-Za-z]+)(&.+)?$   index.php?module=ws&wsType=$1&wsRessource=$2&wsAction=$3$4 [L,QSA]
```

This is what I want to match

`ws/rest/user/get&criteria%5Befezf%5D=%2Ftot%2F&output=dump&compress=&session_id=cb932jrjakosubljl16loecbl1&api_key=a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3`

The problem is around `%2Ftot%2F`. If I remove `%2F` (which is a slash / ), rewrite rule works

Comment: Are you sure that's supposed to be `&` after the "get"? and not a `?`?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure about the `&`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `[B]` flag, *i.e.* `[L,QSA,B]`, or add

```
AllowEncodedSlashes On
```

to Apache, or use `%252F` instead of `%2F`.

Comment: I tried both, but after adding these 2, I got "internal server error". Something's wrong?

Comment: It works by replacing `%252F`, but previous methods not work.